# Spring boot application fials to deploy in a particular environment

Tags: java, jboss, spring-boot, slf4j, logback

I am facing a very unique problem where the spring boot application fails to deploy in a particular  environment. I was able to successfully deploy the application with out an issue in other environment. Following is the stacktace

```
21:06:29,812 ERROR [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS018202: **Error calling onStartup for servlet container initializer: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from vfs:/content/dmcacctservices.war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar). If you are using Weblogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext**
            at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:339) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:151) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLogger(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:143) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:89) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:152) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:139) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:54) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:277) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:119) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:110) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:69) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at com.disney.dmcacctservices.config.DmcacctservicesApplication.onStartup(DmcacctservicesApplication.java:54) [classes:]
            at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:148) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3845) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
```

We even tried copying the JBOSS instance from other environments over to this particular environment and still get the error, eliminating JBOSS being the culprit. we even checked the jdk on the vms and its the same version. 
   The error seems like a classpath issue and can probably be fixed by excluding the logback from the pom file. But the question is how come it works on other environment and whats different in this particular environment. I have exhausted all ideas and would appreciate your input on this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have both Log4j and Logback in your war. Assuming that you want to use Logback, you should exclude Log4j. As for why the problem doesn't happen consistently, I would guess that the jars in `WEB-INF/lib` are being loaded in different orders by JBoss.

Comment: I did exclude slf4j in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file , not sure why its not ignored by the classloader.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<jboss-deployment-structure> 
  <deployment> 
    <dependencies> 
      <module name="com.disney.configuration" /> 
    </dependencies> 
    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies     -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
  </deployment> 
</jboss-deployment-structure>